# 2 relationships of the same tablename confusing SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

IE:

```
class Share(db.Model):
    """
    Stores the Checkpoint shares between users
    """
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_from_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user_from = db.relationship("User")
    user_to_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user_to = db.relationship("User")
```

I get an error:

> ArgumentError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child
>   tables on relationship Share.user_from.  Specify a 'primaryjoin'
>   expression.  If 'secondary' is present, 'secondaryjoin' is needed as
>   well.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error message suggests, you need to specify `primaryjoin` value for your [relationships](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship):

```
class Share(db.Model):
    # ...
    user_from = relationship("User", primaryjoin="Share.user_from_id==User.id")
    user_to = relationship("User", primaryjoin="Share.user_to_id==User.id")
    # ...
```

See [Specifying Alternate Join Conditions to relationship()](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html#specifying-alternate-join-conditions-to-relationship) for more information.